# File not received at server using FormData

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm uploading a form containing a file to my server, which runs validation and returns success or failure.

The form is sent using Ajax and FormData.

On my test server all data, including the file is received. However, on my live server it returns saying that this file is missing.

If i interrogate the FormData object in both environments the file is present, it just never seems to make it to the server.

Obviously i've removed a couple of items and replaced with *s and also the post url is generated by the page.

## HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://******" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group" id="sport_types">
           <label for="match">What match is this video from</label>
           <select id="event_select" name="match" class="form-control">
               <option value="">Select Match</option>
               <option value="9024802136436009">Rugby Newers</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="video">Choose your video</label><br>
           <div class="fileUpload btn btn-info">
              <span id="upload_text">Choose Video</span>
              <input id="imageLoader" accept="video/*" type="file" name="video">
            </div>
             <div id="fileName"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label for="video_name">Enter a short description of the video</label>
           <input name="video_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Video Description" value="">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="0">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="form_buttons_image">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="/video/1451290748440885">Cancel</a>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info  hidden ">
        <span id="uploading_feedback" class="hidden">Uploading Video...</span>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="progress hidden">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
                <span id="progress_label">0%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

## Javascript:

```
    $('form').submit( function( e ) {
    formData = new FormData( this );
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                   var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                   percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                   percentShown = percentComplete*0.98;
                   showProgress(percentShown);
                }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
        },
        url: '{{Request::url()}}/process',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data[0] == 0) {
            console.log( data[1][0] );
            console.log( data[2] );
            $('#feedback').html(data[1][0]).removeClass("hidden");
            $('#key_video').removeClass("hidden");
            $("#uploading_feedback").addClass("hidden");
            $(".progress").addClass("hidden");
        }
        else if (data[0] == 1) { 
            window.location.assign(data[1]);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Are any messages shown in the Console? Check the Network tab: Do you see the POST request? What status does it have?

Comment: No console errors seen. The call is shown in the network tab. Returning with a 200 response. I know this to be true, as the server receives the request and receives data, apart from the file. Is there a way of showing uploads in the network tab?

Answer (score -1):

If your code is working on test server then just check folder permission and folder location. permission should be 777.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, firstly, for those skimming this. You should never 777 anything. Secondly the file is never received over POST, so no permission errors.